# Kafka Broker not available outside of VM Network, even with port forwards

Tags: apache-kafka

Install kafka info :

1. Vmware is installed on the Windows 2016 server.
2. Cent OS 7.1 is installed on Vmware.
3. kafka installed Cent os 7.1.

Cent OS hosts Add :

```
<VM GUEST IP> localhost
```

kafka server.config :

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<VM GUEST IP>:9092
host.name=<VM GUEST IP>
```

VMWare Nat Setting :

```
19092 > <VM GUEST IP>:9092
12181 > <VM GUEST IP>:2181
```

Cent OS Firewall open 9092,2181.

Windows Server port open 19092, 12181.And
Complete the tcping test from another user's computer.

However, there is no connection between Producer and Customer test.

Test :

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list <windows server IP>:19092 --topic <topic>
```

Result N/A But :

```
Connection to node 0 (/<VMWare IP>:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

There was nothing wrong with VMWare.
Similarly, Producer and Customer tests passed correctly on Windows server.

Other users' computers cannot be accessed.What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The `advertised.listeners` needs to expose `19092` if you plan on using clients outside of the VM network.

[See this blog](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/), replacing "Docker/AWS" with "VMWare"

Example configuration

```
listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://<VM address>:19092,EXTERNAL://<Host Address>:9092
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed!